# Error in the recognizer grammar for analyzing data type and variable descriptions in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I need to implement a parser for this type of logic:[the specified grammar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rf76.png)

The **S** character is the initial character of the grammar; L, T, R, V, K, D, F, and E denote nonterminal characters. The terminal character **c** corresponds to one of the two scalar types specified in the task. The terminal character **t** corresponds to one of the data types that can be described in the type section.
I created the following grammar:

```
grammar Parse;
compileString: S+;

S:  TYPE L VAR R;
L:  T (SEPARATOR|SEPARATOR L);
R:  V (SEPARATOR|SEPARATOR R);
V:  [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z]| [0-9]|'_')* DEFINITION (D|C);
T:  D|C;

TYPE:'type';
VAR:'var';

D: // acceptable data types
    'struct'
    | 'union'
    | 'array'
    ;
C:  'byte'
    |'word' //scalar type
;
SEPARATOR:';';
DEFINITION :':';
WS  : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ; // whitespaces
```

But when I try to execute it for the construction: *"type byte; var p1:word;"*, I get the following output:

```
Tokens:
[@0,0:3='type',<6>,1:0]
[@1,5:9='byte;',<2>,1:5]
[@2,11:13='var',<7>,1:11]
[@3,15:22='p1:word;',<3>,1:15]
[@4,23:22='<EOF>',<-1>,1:23]

Parse Tree:
compileString (
  <Error>"type"
  <Error>"byte;"
  <Error>"var"
  <Error>"p1:word;"
)
```

I do not understand what the problem may be, debugging was performed in VS Code with a plugin from Antlr. I will be glad to any answer!

Answer (score 0):

In ANTLR lexer rules start with capital letters and parser rules with lower case letters. So all of your rules except `compileString` are lexer rules.

`S:  TYPE L VAR R;` does not match the input `type byte; var p1:word;` because there are spaces in it and nothing in the definition of `S` matches spaces. You're probably thinking that shouldn't matter because you're skipping spaces, but tokens are only skipped between lexer rules not inside of them. So it would work if `S` were a parser rule, but not as a lexer rule.

The same applies to spaces between the separator and `L`/`R` in `L` and `R`.

PS: I strongly suggest to give your rules longer names as it is quite hard to follow your grammar. You might also consider using the `+` operator in `L` and `R` instead of recursion.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your comment helped me a lot, I did as you advised and everything worked!